# How to get Current-Session-Number of Results Folder in OpenScript?

Tags: java, session, openscript

The `OpenScript` test run results are stored in the results folder under different folders based on the number of runs.

**Example:**

```
results\Session1
results\Session2
```

Now, when I run my script, I don't know what is the folder the latest run goes into.

**My Requirement:**

To get the path of the result file, where the current test's result will be stored. If I know the session number, I can build the path on my own.

But, I am not able to retrieve the session number programmatically.

Any function that I can use?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here it is what should help - `getSettings().get("oats_session_result_dir")`

BR

msl